# how to take input into a character pointer in c++

Tags: c++, input, char

I am using the following code.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  char* str;
  std::cin>>str;
  return 0;
}
```

I obviously understand that str in only a pointer pointing to nothing and hence cannot take an input. But is there a way to take input into a character pointer??

Comment: No, a pointer stores a memory address, not characters.

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Use `std::string`.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit i want to parse the string using a character pointer.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this:

```
int buffer_size = 50
char *c = new char[buffer_size];
std::cin >> std::setw(buffer_size) >> c;
```

However there are problems with this; primarily the fact that it uses a raw array with a fixed size you have to manage. Also it manually manages the lifetime of the array in a non-exception safe manner, though that can be fixed with smart pointers.

```
std::unique_ptr<char[]> c(new char[buffer_size]);
std::cin >> std::setw(buffer_size) >> c.get();
```

Moving entirely away from the raw array to an object that manages its own resources is better:

```
std::string s;
std::cin >> s;
```

If you need a `char const *` from a string you can use `std::string::c_str()`.

```
void foo(char const *);

foo(s.c_str());
```

Or if you really need a `char*` you can do the following:

```
void foo(char *c, size_t n);

foo(s.data(), s.size()); // C++11

// C++03
foo( (s.size() ? &s[0] : NULL), s.size()); // pass a pointer if the string is not empty, NULL otherwise
```

Answer (score 2):

This will work:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  char *str = new char[some_max_size_value];
  cin >> str;
  cout << str;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note that this is a recipe for a buffer overflow.